# How to understand why my MongoDB hangs

Tags: mongodb

I wrote a PyMongo Script to build up large MongoDB tables. When it was almost finished it now suddenly hangs. The guy who set it up says, it's consuming 2GB memory being at the limit.

How I can probe what's going on in general? Are there options the admin should adjust for smooth execution (memory limits, buffer, etc.)?

I looked up db.current_op() and I get:

```
      {'inprog': [{'active': False,
                   'client': '0.0.0.0:0',
                   'desc': 'initandlisten',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {'R': 0,
                                                         'W': 2,
                                                         'r': 6,
                                                         'w': 0},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {'R': 0, 'W': 100416}},
                   'ns': 'test',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'query',
                   'opid': 1,
                   'query': {'options.temp': {'$in': [True, 1]}},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7c7a71b40',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'desc': 'DataFileSync',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {}},
                   'ns': '',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'none',
                   'opid': 0,
                   'query': {},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7c4605700',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'desc': 'journal',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {'R': 278218664,
                                                         'W': 20638320},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {'R': 34804203,
                                                      'W': 313165131}},
                   'ns': '',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'none',
                   'opid': 0,
                   'query': {},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7c3203700',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'client': '0.0.0.0:0',
                   'desc': 'TTLMonitor',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {'r': 2, 'w': 0},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {'r': 32, 'w': 0}},
                   'ns': 'local.system.indexes',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'query',
                   'opid': 22735364,
                   'query': {'expireAfterSeconds': {'$exists': True}},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7c09ff700',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'desc': 'websvr',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {}},
                   'ns': '',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'none',
                   'opid': 0,
                   'query': {},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7bfffe700',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'desc': 'clientcursormon',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {}},
                   'ns': '',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'none',
                   'opid': 0,
                   'query': {},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7c1e01700',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'desc': 'snapshotthread',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {}},
                   'ns': '',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'none',
                   'opid': 0,
                   'query': {},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7c2802700',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'client': '192.168.101.43:52230',
                   'connectionId': 15,
                   'desc': 'conn15',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {}},
                   'ns': '',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'killcursors',
                   'opid': 22735367,
                   'query': {},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7834fb700',
                   'waitingForLock': False},
                  {'active': False,
                   'client': '192.168.101.43:51872',
                   'connectionId': 13,
                   'desc': 'conn13',
                   'lockStats': {'timeAcquiringMicros': {},
                                 'timeLockedMicros': {'r': 0, 'w': 18}},
                   'ns': 'kolibri.nodes',
                   'numYields': 0,
                   'op': 'update',
                   'opid': 22735070,
                   'query': {'_id': 'kolibri-236-237-155368'},
                   'threadId': '0x7fa7833fa700',
                   'waitingForLock': False}]}
```

The operation that seems to be stuck should be an update $push.
Another thing I tried was db.last_status():

```
{'connectionId': 15, 'err': None, 'n': 0, 'ok': 1.0}
```

Can someone help me make sense of this and maybe give some advince (for beginners), how to check what's going on and maybe some useful operations for common errors?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  The mention of a 2GB limit sounds like it may be a [32-bit version](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/32+bit), which would only be suitable for development and working with small data sets.

Comment: connection.server_info() says it's 64bit. I actually wasn't aware of the 32bit problem, so I didn't pay attention. Now, the admin told me the MongoDB is running on a virtual machine which may be limited to 32bit. I suppose that's the issue. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you can also check your server version from the `mongo` shell using `db.serverBuildInfo()`.  Look for the 'bits' setting (ideally should be 64).

Comment: OK. I didn't find this command in PyMongo, but the Mongo command line says it's 64bit. So at least that is right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mongodb has a number of tools that provide some transparency in whats going on within your system. You can try:

- [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongostat/)
- [mongotop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongotop/)
- [mms](http://mms.10gen.com)

The first two should be included with your mongodb install. The third is available free from 10gen.